# When is it useful to have custom construct/destroy methods in allocators?

Tags: c++

Custom allocators, and specifically the ability to customise the `allocate/deallocate` methods are very useful - allowing for control over the low-level memory allocation strategies used in certain performance critical areas. [Pooled allocators](http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184406243) for node-based containers, and [fixed-size allocators](http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/stack_alloc.html) are a few examples that come to mind.

But when is it useful to define custom `construct/destroy` methods?

As I understand it, the standard mandates that these methods have the same effect as placement `new` and explicit destruction, i.e:

```
//construct should give the same effect as:
    construct (_Type *_ptr, _Type const&_val)
    {
        new(_ptr) _Type(_val);
    }
//destroy should give the same effect as:
    destroy (_Type *_ptr)
    {
        _ptr->~_Type();
    }
```

Is there any way to implement these methods in another way - not using placement `new` and explicit destruction? If not, why are they part of the allocator object? Wouldn't it be easier if everyone just used placement `new` and explicit destruction directly?

Comment: The `construct` function could perhaps do something else *in addition to* placement new. This is a customization point, it's good to have if you need it.

Comment: @BoPersson: Is there a practical example of what the "something else" would be? I haven't come up with anything that wouldn't be better placed in the `ctor/dtor` of the actual object type itself... Also, if `construct/destroy` did do something different to plain object creation/destruction, the behaviour of local objects created on the stack would be different to those created through the allocator. Is that reasonable?

Comment: That's one reason for having this functionality in the allocator. Perhaps something special *is* needed when the container is stored  in shared memory? It *allows* contained objects to be different from stack objects.

Comment: More answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/652715/395718

Answer (score 0):

For an allocator that substitutes a wrapper type around the template argument, and operates on that instead, `construct` and `destroy` should call the wrapper constructor and destructor rather than the allocated type.

In C++11, `construct` forwards any number of arguments to the constructor. A custom allocator could insert arguments at the beginning or end of the list, or otherwise intercept and modify arguments. This would only work when the user uses in-place construction, though.

By the way, you should never use `_Type` as an identifier; identifiers with leading underscore followed by capital are reserved for the implementation.