# C++ allocators_trait::construct: motivation, trade-offs in ignoring

Tags: c++, allocation, std

I'm wrestling with some pain being caused by `std::allocator_traits::construct`. In order for a container to be a "conforming" user of the allocator concept, it needs to use `construct` rather than placement new to construct objects. This is very sticky for me. Currently I have a class (class A) that is designed to be allocator aware, and at some point it needs to create another instance of some other class (class B) in allocated memory. The problem is that class B implements the construction of the new object. If I could use placement new, this wouldn't be an issue: A would handle allocation, pass B the memory address, and B would construct into that. But since the construction needs to be performed via construct, I need to inject the allocator type into B, templating it, which creates a huge mess.

It's bad enough that I am seriously considering just using placement new, and static asserting that my instance of the allocator does not have a construct method (note that the static construct function calls the instance method if it exists, otherwise it calls placement new). I have never felt the tiniest urge to write a construct method for an allocator. The cost of making this part of the allocator concept seems very high to me; construction has gotten entangled with allocation, where allocators were supposed to help separate them. What justifies the existence of construct/destruct? Insight into the design decision, examples of real (not toy) use cases, or thoughts on the gravity of electing to simply use placement new appreciated.

There is a similar question; [std::allocator construct/destroy vs. placement new/p->~T()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652715/stdallocator-construct-destroy-vs-placement-new-p-t). It was asked quite a long time ago, and I don't find the answer accepted there as sufficient. Logging is a bit trite as a use case, and even then: why is the allocator logging the actual construction of objects? It can log allocations and deallocations in allocate and deallocate, it doesn't answer the question in the sense of: why was construction made a province of the allocator in the first place? I'm hoping to find a better answer; it's been quite a few years and much about allocators has changed since then (e.g. allocators being stateful since 11).

Comment: `B` constructs itself? With a factory function or what? You could just template that and not the entire class `B`?

Comment: @Brian It's rather complicated. B is not templated on, rather inheritance is involved. B is also more user facing, so I don't want to impose requirements like templates or factories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few points:

- There really isn't a std container concept.  The container requirements tables in the standard are there to document the containers specified by the standard.
- If you have a container that wants to interact with `std::allocator_traits<Alloc>`, all you have to do is assume that `Alloc` conforms to the minimum C++11 allocator requirements and interact with it via `std::allocator_traits<Alloc>`.
- You *are not* required to call `std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::construct`.
- You *are* forbidden from calling `Alloc::construct` because it may not exist.
- The standard-specified containers are required to call `std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::construct` only for `container::value_type`, and are forbidden from using `std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::construct` on any other types the container may need to construct (e.g. internal nodes).

Why was `construct` included in the "allocator concept" way back in C++98?

Probably because the committee at the time felt that this would ease dealing with x86 near and far pointers -- a problem that no longer exists today.

That being said, `std::scoped_allocator_adaptor` is a modern real-world example of an allocator that customizes both `construct` and `destroy`.  For the detailed specification of those customizations I point you towards the latest C++1z working draft, [N4567](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4567.pdf).  The spec is not simple, and that is why I'm not attempting to reproduce it here.